# Get the number of occurrences of a specific pattern in a ruby array

Tags: arrays, ruby

Consider that i have the following

```
array = ["Master Bathroom - Toilet", "Guest Bathroom - Toilet", "Kitchen - Faucet", "Master Bathroom - Faucet"]
```

I need to find out the number of times the pattern "Toilet" appears in the array.

In this case the result should be 2. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array#count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-count):

```
array.count{|e| e.include?('Toilet') }
```

[`String#include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F) checks if string contains a substring. If you want to match a regular expression, you can use [`=~`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Regexp.html#method-i-3D~) with a regex instead.